# C# ASE Encryption crashes DLL with 128 bit Blocksize

Tags: c#, encryption, dll, aes

I am trying to work out why a C# DLL I have is crashing since I added in AES encryption.
I initially put managed rijndael encryption in with a 256 bit key and 256 bit blocksize and the DLL worked, but I found out that the dotnet base receiving end only supports 128 bit blocksize.

However, when I changed the blocksize to 128 bits the DLL simply crashes when I encrypt. I also read the rijndael managed should not be used for new projects and so I tied other examples of AES for C#. All of THESE OTHER EXAMPLES once again crash the DLL as soon as the encrypt function is called.

I am generating both a 64 bit version of the DLL and a 32 bit version of the DLL, both crash as soon as I try to encrypt a string of around 1000 characters.

Is there some sort of initialisation I am missing, or do I need to increase memory / Stack size to use AES in the DLL?  Would really value some suggestions as to why this doesn't work.

This worked for 256 bit blocksize, but crashes for 128 bit blocksize

```
        public static byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
    {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

        // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
        // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                AES.KeySize = 256;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;

                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return encryptedBytes;
    }
```

Various other ways I have tried so far are below:

```
                        byte[] ivBytes = ComputeSHA256(iVphrase);
                    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
                    byte[] keyBytes = ComputeSHA256(password);
                    
                    AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
                    aes.BlockSize = 128;
                    aes.KeySize = 256;
                    aes.Key = keyBytes;
                    aes.IV = ivBytes;
                    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    ICryptoTransform crypto1 = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
                    byte[] encrypteddata = crypto1.TransformFinalBlock(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                    crypto1.Dispose();

                    return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypteddata);

            byte[] encryptedData;
        byte[] ivBytes = ComputeSHA256(iVphrase);
        byte[] keyBytes = ComputeSHA256(password);

        using (Aes aesAlgorithm = new AesManaged())
        {
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes);
             //Encryption will be done in a memory stream through a CryptoStream object
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                    {
                        sw.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encryptedData = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        }

                byte[] ivBytes = ComputeSHA256(iVphrase);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            byte[] keyBytes = ComputeSHA256(password);
                                using (var symmetricKey = Aes.Create("AesManaged"))
                                {
                                    symmetricKey.BlockSize = 128;
                                    symmetricKey.Mode      = CipherMode.CBC;
                                    symmetricKey.Padding   = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                                    symmetricKey.Key       = keyBytes;
                                    symmetricKey.IV        = ivBytes;
                                    using (var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
                                    {
                                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                                        {
                                            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                                            {
                                                cs.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                                                cs.Close();
                                            }
                                            var cipherBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                                            memoryStream.Close();
                                            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherBytes);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
```

Comment: *...crashes DLL...* that's not an adequate description, please include the exact error message and the line in your code that cause the crash, and ideally any call stack information provided in the crash dump.

Comment: Hello James, there is no error message   the application calling my dll simply crashes, it doesn't give an exception. The aes fails on either setting of the iv or on calling of the initial function.  I believe the issue may be related to the fact that all the aes implementations seem to be managed, but my dll is unmanaged.  However, I can find no information to confirm this and cannot find an unmanaged aes implementation in the c# functions.

Comment: That should say "init" function. `Aes aesAlgorithm = new AesManaged()` fails at  `aesAlgorithm.IV = ivBytes;` or at `CryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes);`  and `var cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING");` fails at `cipher.init(true, keyParameters).`

Comment: I did some further research.  I inherited this code from a previous employee. The DLL that I am making provides an interface which is unmanaged and marshals the incoming char * to the .net String for use by the internal functions of the DLL itself. So I know its not managed / unmanaged that is the issue. The windows event viewer simply shows as 0xe0434352 which is an unkown exception and says possibly relates to a bad .net install.  As the error exists on 3 different computers I find this hard to believe all have corrupt .net installs.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get an exception output which identified the issue as being a 32 byte IV being passed in to a 128 bit Block size which generated an exception.  On windows server machines the exception didn't return any result code, it simply crashed the machine.  Testing on another windows 10 device correctly logged the incorrect IV length as an exception.

Comment: For the 2nd code snippet this is plausible, since the IV is determined as SHA256 hash: `byte[] ivBytes = ComputeSHA256(iVphrase);`. For the 1st code snippet however, this actually cannot be the cause, since there only a 16 bytes IV is applied: `AES.BlockSize = 128;...AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);`.